# How to perform a swap on raydium with Python

Tags: solana-program, python

so I've written a simple crypto trading bot as a little project and so far im trading using the Jup API but its quite buggy and so I would like to try using raydium but Im a bit lost on how to do it in python as there isnt much info out there, if anyone could provide any help? Thanks